# External routing issue with server side rendering in React/Node app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I have a very weird problem, if I run my app with client side rendering then all the routes work perfectly. However when I switch to SSR then it runs fine initially on http://localhost:8001
but when I load a new get request by hitting enter in the browser search bar to load a different route such as
http://localhost:8001/covid
then I get this error...
This was generated with create-react-app

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function.
> Received undefined
> at maybeCallback (fs.js:160:9)
> at Object.readFile (fs.js:311:14)
> at D:\Repo\WhiteTigerCreateReactApp\server/server.js:37:8
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Repo\WhiteTigerCreateReactApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at next (D:\Repo\WhiteTigerCreateReactApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
> at Route.dispatch (D:\Repo\WhiteTigerCreateReactApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Repo\WhiteTigerCreateReactApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at D:\Repo\WhiteTigerCreateReactApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
> at param (D:\Repo\WhiteTigerCreateReactApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:354:14)
> at param (D:\Repo\WhiteTigerCreateReactApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)

Here is my nodeJS file where I load the react app, I have commented out the line I use for client side render

```
import express from 'express';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDomServer from 'react-dom/server'

import App from '../src/components/App'
const PORT = 8001;

const app = express();

let indexPath = path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html');
let buildPath = path.join(__dirname, '../build');

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build')));

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    
    console.log("response",indexPath);

    //SSR -------------------------
    fs.readFile(indexPath), 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error from server.js', err);
            return res.status(500).send("Some error happened")
        }
        return res.send(data.replace(
            "<div id='root'></div>",
            `<div id="root">${ReactDomServer.renderToString(<App />)} </div>`));
    }
    //Client Render -----------------
    //res.sendFile(indexPath);   

});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App launced on ${PORT}`);
});
```

This is wrapped up with a seperate server file which is the one I am calling. This calls the code above.

```
require('ignore-styles')

require('@babel/register')({
    ignore: [/(node_module)/],
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
})

require('./server')
```

My react app has this entry point

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

/* ./ means search local file system*/
import './assets/css/styles.css';
import './assets/css/utility.css';
import './assets/css/animate.min.css';
import './assets/css/call-now.css';
import './assets/css/Contact-Form-Clean.css';
import './assets/css/betternav.min.css';
import App from './components/App';
//when importing from a module the file extension is omitted. */
import '../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.hydrate(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
    <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);    

reportWebVitals();
```

And my App component looks like this which has all the routes.. clearly something is not working or loading during SSR? :/

```
import { React, Component } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import '../assets/css/header.css';
import '../assets/css/footer.css';
import Header from './header';
import Footer from './footer';
import Body from './body';
import ClientPage from './clientPage'
import CovidPage from './covidPage'
import Commercial from './commercialPage'
import CarpetFloorPage from './carpetFloor'
import IndustrialConstructionPage from './industrialConstructionPage';
import SafeContractorPage from './safeContractor';
import ContactPage from './contactPage';
import IndustrialCommercialPage from './industrialCommercialPage';
import Popper from 'popper.js';
import BetterNav from '../utility/betternav'
import PageNotFound from './notFoundPage';

class App extends Component { 


  componentDidMount()
  {
    BetterNav();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header></Header>
        <Switch>          
          <Route exact path='/' component={Body} />          
          <Route path='/clients' component={ClientPage} />
          <Route path='/covid' component={CovidPage} />
          <Route path='/commercial' component={Commercial} />       
          <Route path='/carpet-floor' component={CarpetFloorPage} /> 
          <Route path='/industrial-construction' component={IndustrialConstructionPage} /> 
          <Route path='/safe-contractor' component={SafeContractorPage} />          
          <Route path='/contact' component={ContactPage} />
          <Route path='/industrial-commercial' component={IndustrialCommercialPage} />                     
          <Route component={PageNotFound} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer></Footer>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
}

export default App;
```

Since updating the code in server.js to

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    
    console.log("response",indexPath);

    //SSR -------------------------
    fs.readFile(indexPath, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error from server.js', err);
            return res.status(500).send("Some error happened")
        }
        return res.send(data.replace(
            "<div id='root'></div>",
            `<div id="root">${ReactDomServer.renderToString(<App />)} </div>`));
    })
    //Client Render -----------------
    //res.sendFile(indexPath);   

});
```

The app loads at first with
http://localhost:8001 no problem as usual. but when I go to
http://localhost:8001/covid
I get this error instead..

> D:\Repo\WhiteTigerCreateReactApp\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3709
> throw err;
> ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined
> at App.render (D:\Repo\WhiteTigerCreateReactApp\src\components/App.js:30:7)
> at processChild (D:\Repo\WhiteTigerCreateReactApp\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3450:18)
> at resolve (D:\Repo\WhiteTigerCreateReactApp\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3270:5)
> at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (D:\Repo\WhiteTigerCreateReactApp\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3753:22)
> at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (D:\Repo\WhiteTigerCreateReactApp\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3690:29)
> at Object.renderToString (D:\Repo\WhiteTigerCreateReactApp\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:4298:27)
> at D:\Repo\WhiteTigerCreateReactApp\server/server.js:27:46
> at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:63:3) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm
> ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! ssr-example@0.1.0 ssr: `node server/index.js`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the
> ssr-example@0.1.0 ssr script.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here:

```
fs.readFile(indexPath), 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
    // ........ (Your code was here)
}
```

Change it to:

```
fs.readFile(indexPath, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
    // ........ (Your code was here)
})
```

You've just missed the bracket.

Comment: Updated it but that caused a very different error,, will update the ticket.

Comment: You are actually right, you need a serverside webpack.